# Any difference between “Are you done?” and “Are you done yet?”

Tags: meaning, adverbs, connotation, nuance

I see people in movies saying

> Are you done?

and

> Are you done **yet**?

And I wonder what that the addition of *yet* might mean or suggest in the second version which is absent in the first one.

Are those two versions completely equivalent, or is there some subtle distinction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of *yet* here emphasizes that it has taken a reasonable amount of time or that it has taken too long and implicitly expects an answer in the affirmative.

“Are you done?” is just a question to find out whether he is done with it, whereas “Are you done yet” says you had better get done soon if you aren’t already.